# Zip for every output

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have two Observables of type `boolean` . I want to zip them so that end result is true if either of them are true.

```
Rx.Observable.zip(firstBooleanSource$, SecondBooleanSource$)
    .map((results: boolean[]) => results.some( (result:boolean)=>result))
    .subscribe(( status: boolean)=> console.log(status));
```

..

```
----FALSE-----------
----FALSE---TRUE----
```

Will result in

```
----FALSE----
```

Expecting:

```
----FALSE----TRUE----
```

Comment: So you want something like this `Rx.Observable.merge(firstBooleanSource$, SecondBooleanSource$).filter(Boolean).subscribe(...)`?

Comment: ^ this way I will never know when both are false. If I remove `filter` , if first is true, second is false, it takes second result and show false. While it should actually show true. JSBIN: https://jsbin.com/hekupemuye/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [`combineLatest`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest) operator so it combines the values so you can map it to the correct result

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pass to `zip` function that will merge your `Observables`. According to documentation:

> `zip` accepts a variable number of Observables or Promises as parameters, followed by a function that accepts one item emitted by each of those Observables or resolved by those Promises as input and produces a single item to be emitted by the resulting Observable.

So, your code can look like:

```
Rx.Observable.zip(
    firstBooleanSource$, SecondBooleanSource$,
    (first,second) => first && second)
.subscribe((status: boolean) => console.log(status));`
```

Comment: This is better syntax than what I wrote but it didn't solve my problem. Bin: https://jsbin.com/pitenucosi/edit?js,console,output